# JAVA_HOME not set in script when run using sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I'm trying to run an install script that requires java to be installed and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to be set.

I've set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile` and also in a file I've called `java.sh` in `/etc/profile.d`.  I can `echo $JAVA_HOME` and get the correct response and I can even `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME` and get the correct response.

In the `install.sh` I'm trying to run, I inserted an `echo $JAVA_HOME`.  When I run this script without `sudo` I see the java directory; when I run the script with `sudo` it is blank.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm running CentOS.

Comment: I have also experienced this issue running Ubuntu 14.04, both proposed answers worked for me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For security reasons, `sudo` may clear environment variables which is why it is probably not picking up $JAVA_HOME. Look in your `/etc/sudoers` file for `env_reset`.

From `man sudoers`:

> ```
> env_reset   If set, sudo will reset the environment to only contain the following variables: HOME, LOGNAME, PATH, SHELL, TERM, and USER (in addi-
>            tion to the SUDO_* variables).  Of these, only TERM is copied unaltered from the old environment.  The other variables are set to
>            default values (possibly modified by the value of the set_logname option).  If sudo was compiled with the SECURE_PATH option, its value
>            will be used for the PATH environment variable.  Other variables may be preserved with the env_keep option.
>
> env_keep    Environment variables to be preserved in the user's environment when the env_reset option is in effect.  This allows fine-grained con-
>            trol over the environment sudo-spawned processes will receive.  The argument may be a double-quoted, space-separated list or a single
>            value without double-quotes.  The list can be replaced, added to, deleted from, or disabled by using the =, +=, -=, and ! operators
>            respectively.  This list has no default members.
> ```

So, if you want it to keep JAVA_HOME, add it to env_keep:

```
Defaults   env_keep += "JAVA_HOME"
```

**Alternatively**, set `JAVA_HOME` in root's `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Yea, that was it.  Had no idea one could do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Run sudo with the -E (preserve environment) option (see the man file), or put JAVA_HOME in the install.sh script.

Comment: The -E option is not available in CentOS.

Comment: Thanks for -E, great tip.