# Can't export variables within script

Tags: linux, environment-variables, borgbackup

I've been trying to setup a borg automated backup script following the documentation. For some reason my script fails to see its variables while I'm trying to write to a sudo protected encrypted drive.

For example, something like this works as the script as the script doesn't ask me a password again.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date --iso-8601)-$(hostname)
TARGET=~/Documents/borg
export BORG_PASSPHRASE="whatever"
borg init --encryption=repokey $TARGET
borg create $TARGET::$DATE-$$ ~/Desktop/TestFolder/1
```

However when I mount an external FDE implemented drive, it ignores the exported password and and weirdly enough the "repokey" encryption mode.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date --iso-8601)-$(hostname)
TARGET=~/X/borg
export BORG_PASSPHRASE="whatever"
sudo borg init --encryption=repokey $TARGET
sudo borg create $BORG_OPTS $TARGET::$DATE-$$ ~/Desktop/TestFolder/1
```

I'm fairly new to Linux so this is probably an easy fix but I couldn't do it on my own when I referred to other answers. Please help.

Comment: you're running it through `sudo`, and it can well filter away environment variables. Try e.g. `export BORG_PASSPHRASE=test; sudo sh -c 'echo $BORG_PASSPHRASE'` to see if it prints anything. Also I can't see you set `BORG_OPTS` anywhere, even though the second script uses it

Comment: Possibly related: [JAVA_HOME not set in script when run using sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/java-home-not-set-in-script-when-run-using-sudo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo does not preserve env vars, try the `-E` option. See `man 8 sudo`

> -E' The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Comment: Sorry couldn't accept it before, this is a guest account (which doesn't allow an upvote). Thank you very much.